# Pointer Indexing: Getting Unexpected Values

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, memory, indexing

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int* computeSquares(int& n)
{
    int arr[10];
    n = 10;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        arr[k] = (k + 1) * (k + 1);
return arr;
}

void f()
{
    int junk[100];
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++)'
        junk[k] = 123400000 + k;
}

int main()
{
    int m;
    int* ptr = computeSquares(m);
    f();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
         cout << ptr[i] << ' ';
    }
}
```

The above code should print:

```
1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64 81 100
```

However, it instead prints random integer values that don't make any sense, at least after the first one. After running the code through the debugger, the ptr address is deleted right after the first run of the for loop in the main method and I cannot fathom why. Additionally, I have no idea what the purpose of the f() method is, I don't think it should change anything but when I remove it from the main the first value returns accurately (everything after is still wrong.) What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int *computeSquares(int &n) {
    int *arr = new int[10];
    n = 10;
    for (int k = 0; k < n; k++)
        arr[k] = (k + 1) * (k + 1);
    return arr;
}
```

The memory of "int arr[10]" is released after computeSquares finished running.

Comment: Thanks MsrButterfly, your solution clearly works. However, are there solutions that don't use dynamic arrays? I was not aware of dynamic arrays until a friend just told me about them, so I'm not sure if I can use them. I appreciate the fact that you fixed the problem though, and I can see why it works through the debugger

Comment: @RawN is correct, sorry for the inaccurate description. I mean the variable in your original code will be automatically released after the code goes out of the function scope.

Comment: @jaytrinitron: You should allocate the memory before the function call, and pass a pointer to the function like **void computeSquares(int &n, int *arr)**, or just use C++ standard library containers like **std::array** or **std::vector**.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this result because you are misunderstanding basic language features. In addition to MsrButterfly's answer, who pointed out the most important problem already, let me please give you the following advices:

- forget about using raw pointers; it is dangerous practice, very hard to maintain and extend, and will for sure lead you to write code with memory leaks. You will be better off having a look at some STL documentation which possesses e.g. the std::vector container that you could use instead of your array arr
- your computeSquares method is dangerous in the sense that you take a variable n a argument which should be your array's size. In your method, you first define arr with a hard-coded size of 10 and then you set n = 10; I'd suggest you avoid that kind of constructs as you have in this case to maintain two variables that depend on that number 10.

Comment: You answer is really helpful for the questioner. But my nickname is MsrButterfly not MrsButterfly. That sounds like an old woman. :(